# Blur & Flicker issue on CSS transform

Tags: html, css

I found quite a few questions here with solutions too, but none seem to work for me. After the scale up, the text is blurry and then it flickers into position. Something wrong with the rendering.

I made a fiddle with the exact structure I'm trying to use, if someone has a solution for it, I'd appreciate it.

I want to underline that I've tried the solutions I found here, but none helped, or I haven't been able implement them as intended.

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/1yu9p66L/1/

```
.box1:hover {
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.09);
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

PS: Currently testing on FF 45.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Add transform to the original box that scales it to < 1 and then change the transform in hover state to 1. You'll need to adjust the sizes of the box.

This to .box1, for example:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(.9);
-ms-transform: scale(.9);
-moz-transform: scale(.9);
transform: scale(.9);
```

and this to .box1:hover

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-ms-transform: scale(1);
-moz-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1yu9p66L/2/

Comment: Thank you. At first glance it seems to work, but it just reverses the flickering issue to when the box scales out.

Got to admit, it's not that annoying anymore because it's out of focus, but when you plan on having three of these boxes on the live website and you hover, by accident or not, on all of them in one mouse move, the unwanted effect really stands out.

Comment: @AndreiP I'm not exactly sure what you mean by flickering, but I think maybe it is because of the change of the background color.

Comment: At the end of the animation the box is blurry, then it sharpens up and seems to be moving by 1px up-down until it snaps in its final position. I did a little research and saw people having the same issues, others giving solutions that don't work in this case. I also thought that it may be something inside the div as well and removed effects & elements, but the issue persisted.